# How to extract a particular column of data in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have some data from a unix commandline call

```
1  ab  45  1234
2  abc 5
4  yy  999 2
3  987 11
```

I'll use the `system()` function for the call.

**How can I extract the second column of data into an array in Perl?** Also, the array size has to be dependent on the number of rows that I have (it will not necessarily be 4).

I want the array to have `("ab", "abc", "yy", 987)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = "1  ab  45  1234
2  abc 5
2  abc 5
2  abc 5
4  yy  999 2
3  987 11";

my @second_col = map { (split)[1] } split /\n/, $data;
```

To get unique values, see [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f). Here's part of the answer provided there:

```
my %seen;
my @unique = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } @second_col;
```

Comment: @Lazer It declares the variable within the current lexical scope. Your asking this question suggests that you are not enabling `use strict` and possibly `use warnings` in your Perl scripts. If not, you should start doing so.

Comment: @FM: thanks! while this solves my immediate problem, is there a simple way to get only unique results in `second_col`?

Comment: There are multiple ways of removing duplicates from the array, and perlfaq explains it very nicely. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array?

Answer (score 4):

You can chain a Perl cmd-line call  (aka: [*one-liner*](http://sial.org/howto/perl/one-liner/)) to your unix script:

```
 perl -lane 'print $F[1]' data.dat
```

instead of data.dat, use a pipe from your command line tool

```
 cat data.dat | perl -lane 'print $F[1]'
```

**Addendum**:

The extension for unique-ness of the resulting column is straightforward:

```
cat data.dat | perl -lane 'print $F[1] unless $seen{$F[1]}++'
```

or, if you are lazy (employing %_):

```
cat data.dat | perl -lane 'print unless $_{$_=$F[1]}++'
```

Comment: Good answer, must have been nice to explicitly state that the `-a` option autosplits to `@F`. Not sure what `-l` does though...

Comment: @PP, -l does the proper *new line* handling, see: http://sial.org/howto/perl/one-liner/ , ok, I added a link for explanation (thanks)