# Perl Function Extracting Data with Specified Start Columns and Length

Tags: perl, extract

I am trying to write a code that extracts data from File A and pastes only column data with specified start and end point into File B. So far, I am only able to successfully Copy all of the data from A to B - but am not getting anywhere with filtering out the columns. I've tried looking into splice and grep with no avail. Not experienced in Perl. The data has no column headers. 
Sample: The data is actually thousands of lines long - can't insert data into function

```
1. AAA 565 u8y 221
2. ABC 454 9u8 352
3. ADH 115 i98 544
4. AKS 352 87y 454
5. GJS 154 i9k 141
```

I want all unique values of the 3rd column (start:8 length:3) to be copied into the File B. I have tried solutions provided in [How to extract a particular column of data in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573678/how-to-extract-a-particular-column-of-data-in-perl) to no avail.

Thanks for any tips or assistance!

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#use Cwd qw(abs_path);

#my $dir = '/home/
#$dir = abd_path($dir);
my $filename = "filea.txt";
my $newfilename = "fileb.txt"; 

#Open file to read raw data
open (DATA1, "<$filename") or die "Couldn't open $filename: $!";

#Open new file to copy desired columns
open (DATA2, ">$newfilename") or die "Couldn't open $newfilename: $!";

#Copy data from original to new file

while (<DATA1>) {
    #DATA2=splice(DATA1, 0,5);
    print DATA2 $_;
    my @fifth_column = map{(split)[1]} split /\n/, $newfilename;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a rather simple script for this, if I understand you correctly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;
while (<DATA>) {
    my $str = substr($_, 8, 3);   # the string you seek
    unless ($seen{$str}++) {      # if it is not seen before
        print "$str\n";           # ...print it
    }
}

__DATA__
AAA 565 u8y 221
AAA 565 u8y 221
ABC 454 9u8 352
ADH 115 i98 544
AKS 352 87y 454
GJS 154 i9k 141
```

**Output:**

```
u8y
9u8
i98
87y
i9k
```

The `DATA` file handle is used for demonstration here. I also added a duplicate in the data to demonstrate the deduping. If you change `<DATA>` to `<>` you can simply use the script like so:

```
perl script.pl filea.txt > fileb.txt
```

**Note** that this relies on your data being *fixed width*, meaning that if your fields do not line up, your output will be corrupted.

Also note that this is just a full version of a simple one-liner like such:

```
perl -nlwe '$x=substr($_,8,3); print $x unless $seen{$x}++' filea.txt > fileb.txt
```

Comment: The one-liner works great! Thank you so much for informing me of that option! It does spit out the below warning - even though it gives me the correct output. @TLP                                                Name "main::seen" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.

Comment: Meant to add - Im not terribly worried about the warning...just an FYI @TLP

Comment: @todayspresent That warning is not relevant. It is there only because we are in fact doing two things as once, `unless $seen{$x}++` is really short for `unless $seen{$x}; $seen{$x}++;`. Plus the fact that the one-liner does not use strict, so we don't declare the variable. If you feel that your question has been answered, you can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Comment: Thanks! For the most part it is answered. @TLP Upon using the code, it includes some values that it shouldn't. For example, in the output above - if I wanted omit those with 'i' in the front. is there a way I can get `unless $seen{$x}++` to also work with `unless substr($_,0,1) ne 'i'`? Let me know if I need to enter this as a different question. Thanks!

Comment: @todayspresent Well, you can do `if (!/^i/ && !$seen{$_}++)` Assuming I got all the negations right there, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following Perl commands:

- **[`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)**: This allows you to split up a line of data into an array:

Example:

```
while ( my $line = <$input_fh> ) {
    my @items = split /\s+/, $line;   #Columns are separated by spaces or tabs
    my $third_column = $items[2];  #The column you want;
    blah...blah...blah;
}
```

- **[`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html)**: This allows you to specify a substring of your column information. This might not be as useful if your columns are separated by tabs. For most non-Perl developers, this is the first method they try. However, I recommend using `split`.

There's a Perl trick for making sure your data is unique: Use a hash to store your information. Looking up a data in a hash is quick, and the [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) function can be used to quickly look up if you've already seen that data. Combining this with `split`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use constants {
    INPUT_FILE  => "filea.txt",
    OUTPUT_FILE => "fileb.txt",
};

open my $input_fh, "<", INPUT_FILE;
open my $output_fh ">", OUTPUT_FILE;

my %unique_columns;
while ( my $line = <$input_fh> ) {
    my @items = split /\s+/, $line;   #Columns are separated by spaces or tabs
    my $third_column = $items[2];  #The column you want;
    if ( not exists $unique_columns{$third_column} ) {
        $unique_columns{$third_column} = 1;
        print {$output_fh} "$third_column\n";
    }
}
close $output_fh;
```

The `%unique_columns` hash tracks to see if you've seen that data before in the third columns of your file. It doesn't matter what you set each individual key equal to. However, I recommend setting it to a non-zero or blank value because if you did this:

```
if ( $unique_columns{$data} )
```

instead of

```
if ( exists $unique_columns{$data} )
```

your program will still work as long as the value of `$unique_columns{$data}` isn't zero or blank, but fail otherwise.

Comment: This is very helpful - I will have to look into what lines to use to replace the "blahs" and "yaddas" - thanks for explaining! :-) @David W.

Comment: The yaddas would be:  
print DATA2 $third_column;

Comment: @todayspresent - I've updated my answer to show the whole program.

Comment: Ah gotcha! Thanks! @David W.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to fixed length nothing beats pack/unpack, Learn this tutorial and it will make your life easier and this job a piece of cake.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/perlpacktut

Comment: The template `(A4)*` should `unpack` your strings.